# Ejabberd Clustering in EC2

Tags: cluster-computing, ejabberd

I am newbie in Ejabberd. I installed two nodes in Ubuntu Amazon EC2 and using Amazon Public DNS ec2-00-00-00-00.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

When I tried to do cluster, I received message with no_ping.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: What was the message?

Comment: Hi it is Error: {no_ping,'ejabberd@ecx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com'}